# Can include files be nested?

Tags: c

please explain with program

Comment: Yes they can, but why didn't you just try it to check?

Comment: There is probably a better, real question you're trying to get answered; asking that would probably be more helpful for you.

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  puts("Yes");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    #include "include.h"

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

include.h:

```
#include "nested.h"
```

nested.h:

```
printf("yes.\n");
```

Comment: I'd avoid "headers" being included within a function, but otherwise yours is better than mine! :) (I was merely using a program instead of trying to demonstrate.)

Comment: Heh, yes, I almost wrote that version myself.

Comment: If this was real code and that include was unavoidable, I'd probably rename the include files to have a ".c" or a completely different extension (not to mention, a better filename.).

Comment: I strongly prefer to avoid both *.h and *.c in that case, since it can neither be included as a normal header nor compiled as a normal implementation file.  I use *.inc unless the given project already has a convention.  (Since you mentioned it. :P)